# onCreateOptionsMenu not called on SherlockFragment under FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, fragmentpageradapter, oncreateoptionsmenu

I have a SherlockFragment that works properly when inflated in a `SherlockActivity`. I set `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` on `onCreate()` and `onCreateOptionsMenu()` function in that fragment is properly called.

The problem is when I call the fragment under a `FragmentPagerAdapter` with `getItem()`, `onCreateOptionsMenu()` function is not called.

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```